# Form results display only if I click the "Submit" button twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I've created a flask website such that the form and its respective results display on the same page. The problem I'm having is that, when I first do `flask run` and load the website, the first time I click the 'submit' button, I get the following key error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2019 14:40:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2019 14:40:11] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2019 14:40:16] "POST /process_file HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2019 14:40:16] "GET /upload_vals?payload=%7B%22affiliation%22%3A%22number%22%2C%22period%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22space%22%3A%22no%22%7D HTTP/1.1" 500

  File "/Users/cdastmalchi/Desktop/author_script/app.py", line 106, in upload_vals
    proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(flask.session['filename'], 'y' if payload['period'] == 'yes' else 'n', 'y' if payload['space'] == 'yes' else 'n', payload['affiliation'][:3]), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Users/cdastmalchi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 378, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
  File "/Users/cdastmalchi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    return super(SecureCookieSession, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'filename'
```

However, if I click the submit button a second time, my results get displayed as normal. Even weirder is that, if I don't kill the flask app and simply do a hard refresh on the web page, then submit the form again, this time, the results display only with one click instead of two.

How can I get it so that, if I've just started the flask app, it only takes one click of the submit to display the results?

**SOURCE CODE**

**app.py:**

```
TEMPLATE_FILE = 'ExampleAuthorList.txt'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '.'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt'])

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.config['TEMPLATE_FILE'] = TEMPLATE_FILE
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.secret_key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(20)) #needed to use flask.session

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
   return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process_file', methods=['POST'])
def process_file():
  #here, you can run all the checks as before, but instead of flash, you can return jsonified results to read in the front-end
    if 'file' not in flask.request.files or not flask.request.files['file'].filename:
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'no files selected'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file = flask.request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'Must be TXT file!'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    if not places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    flask.session['filename'] = filename
    return flask.jsonify({'result':'True'})

@app.route('/upload_vals')
def upload_vals():
    payload = json.loads(flask.request.args.get('payload'))
    proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(flask.session['filename'], 'y' if payload['period'] == 'yes' else 'n', 'y' if payload['space'] == 'yes' else 'n', payload['affiliation'][:3]), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while proc.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    with open("templates/authorList.html") as f:
        data = ''.join(f.readlines())
    return flask.jsonify({'data':data})
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico"> 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container" id="TheForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1><img src="static/Lab_Logo_v6c.png" style="width: 120px; float: left;margin-right: 20px;margin-left: -16px;margin-top: -40px;border: 10px">Author List Script</h1>
      <br><br><br>
      <p>Download the template file below and re-upload with your custom author information:</p>
      <br>
      <a href="static/ExampleAuthorList.txt" download="Authors_Template.txt"><button type="button">Download</button></a><br><br>
        <form action="" id="myform" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
           <input type=file name=file value="Choose File">
           <p class='error_message'></p>
        </form>
         <div id="buttonDiv">
            <p>Mark affiliations with:</p> 
            <input type="radio" name="affiliation" value="number" data-key='affiliation' data-value='number' class="form-radio main_checkbox" checked><label for="number">Number</label><br> 
            <input type="radio" name="affiliation" value="letter" data-key='affiliation' data-value='letter' class="form-radio main_checkbox"><label for="letter">Letter</label><br> 
           <p>Separate initials with period:</p> 
           <input type="radio" name="period" value="separated" data-key='period' data-value='yes' class="form-radio period"><label for="period">Yes</label><br> 
           <input type="radio" name="period" data-key='period' data-value='no' value="separated" class="form-radio period" checked><label for="period">No</label> 
           <br> 
           <p>Separate initials with space:</p> 
           <input type="radio" name="space" value="separated" data-key='space' data-value='yes' class="form-radio spacing"><label for="space">Yes</label><br> 
           <input type="radio" name="space" data-key='space' data-value='no' value="separated" class="form-radio spacing" checked><label for="space">No</label><br> 
        </div>
        <button class='submit_data'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div>
          <h1>Results</h1>
          <p class="my-results"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#TheForm').on('click', '.submit_data', function(){
          var form_data = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
          var flag = true;

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/process_file',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              if (data.result === 'False'){
                $('.error_message').html(data.message)
                flag = false;
              }
            },
          });

          var payload = {};

          $('.form-radio').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('checked')){
              payload[$(this).data('key')] = $(this).data('value');
            }
          });

          $.ajax({
            url: "/upload_vals",
            type: "get",
            data: {'payload':JSON.stringify(payload)},
            success: function(response) {
              $(".my-results").html(response.data);
            },
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The submit button is not inside the `<form>` container.

Comment: If your `/upload_vals` ajax call is expected to return the new results, then this is most likely an async issue, as you are going to be making your ajax call to `/process_file` and `/upload_vals` pretty much at the same time.

Comment: @F.Igor: When I put the submit button inside the `<form>` container, and then click submit, it redirects me to a page that says `Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.`

Comment: @Taplar that may very well be what's going wrong. Do you have a concrete suggestion for how to proceed? I'm not fluent in JavaScript/Ajax at all.

Comment: Yes, put the call to the /upload_vals in the success callback of the first ajax call.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the `filename` key is not in `session` (at least after the first call).

If I'm thinking correctly, the solution should be:

```
def process_file():

    ...
    flask.session['filename'] = filename
    flask.session.modified = True

    return ...
```

Comment: I get `NameError: global name 'session' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry! Should be `flask.session.modified` in your case